# Difference between typing two elements tags on the same line in editor and using new line to make them in spearate lines (inline-block) elements

Tags: html, css

I noticed a strange behavior when I made a block element like `<p>` to an inline-block.

CSS

```
div {
    background-color: #4832d5;
    width: 500px;
}

p {
    background-color: #ccf281;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}
```

The first case:

```
<div>
  <p>First</p>
  <p>Second</p>
</div>
```

In this one the First

element causing the Second to shift to the next line

[First case output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xriUQ.png)

The second case:

```
<div>
  <p>First</p><p>Second</p>
</div>
```

In this case the two elements are on the same line in the editor with no space between them, also making the two elements beside each other in the box.

[Second case output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYVh8.png)

My question here is how typing them on the same line in editor change their behavior because as I know the browser rendering the extra whitespace

I tried it with other block elemetns by making them inline-block and get the same output

Comment: I don't have enough time right now to write an answer, but to summarise - the whitespace inbetween the elements is pushing the second element onto the next line as if it was wrapping. if the total width is 500px and each <p> element is 250px wide, that means it'll need to accommodate a space in-between which is, let's say, 4px wide - this exceeds the 500px of its container so it wraps

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ might be helpful

Answer (score -1):

in the first case parent contains 2 elements each 50% width - it can place them on one line.

in the second case there is a space between two `<p>` and thus there is no space for two 50% elements and a space. to prevent that you could add a comment instead of a space

```
</p><!-- html comment
--><p>
```

or (rarely applicable, but would still work) by making parent font size (and thus space element size) 0.

```
div {
  font-size: 0;
}

p {
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

---

I would use css-grid in your case to make equal elements

```
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

or if you like flexbox more

```
div {
  display: flex;
}

p {
  flex: 1 1 0; // 1 flex-grow to grow them equally, 1 for flex-srink (doesn't matter in this case) and 0 for start size from which elements will grow or shrink depending on the available space
}
```